# How can I put rout53 infront of appsync endpoint without cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-appsync

I am building a graphql server using AWS appsync. It generates a random endpoint URL and I'd like to put it behind a DNS customer domain. I have read this article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/use-a-custom-domain-with-aws-appsync-amazon-cloudfront-and-amazon-route-53/ and it mentions cloudfront. I don't really need any cache for my application so I wonder why do I need cloudfront?

Can route53 forward the request to appsync endpoint? I don't understand why I need cloudfront. I thought route53 can work as a proxy to forward request from customised domain to target domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open GitHub issue for this feature:

- [Feature Request: Custom domain name](https://github.com/aws/aws-appsync-community/issues/5)

Based on the issue, the use of CloudFront as in your link, seems to be the only feasible way for now to have custom domains with SSL certificates for your appsync endpoint. Using API Gateway to proxy requests to your endpoint also seems as a possibility.

Comment: Can route53 forward the request to appsync endpoint? I don't understand why I need cloudfront. I thought route53 can work as a proxy to forward request from customised domain to target domain.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao You can create CNAME record off course, but I think you will encounter issues with SSL certificates, as for HTTPS you will need certificate matching your domain.